# Retirar número por número de uma sequencia de números para compara-los

Tags: c, c++, string

Meu professor de algorítimos e técnicas de programação passou um exercício em que `a = "123567348"` e disso eu diria quais números são pares e quais são primos. Ele disse que teria que usar `substr()`, e passou um exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
int main ()
{
int c;
char a [] = "123456789", pedaco;
for (c = 1; c <= 10 ; c++) 
pedaco = a.substr(c,1);
  return 0;
}
```

mas retorna o erro:

> 8 12 [Error] request for member 'substr' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'char [10]'

No exemplo que ele deu era: `pedaco = substr(a,c,1);` e também não funcionava.

Comment: Se cada pedaço é apenas uma letra, porque não aceder diretamente com `a[c]` ? (e teria que começar no indice 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está misturando C com C++ e acho que isto é o problema, diz que foi orientado a usar `substr()`, só só faz sentido em usar a *string* nativa do C++ e não usar o mecanismo do C para criar algo parecido com uma *string*. Se fosse C puro não existe `substr()`. Seria Assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a = "123456789";
    for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) cout << a.substr(c, 1);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/W8BHDR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lguzrldh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/EachCharSubstr.cpp).

Se não precisasse deste método poderia fazer melhor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    string a = "123456789";
    for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) cout << a[c];
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/W8BHDR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gmmfqpup-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/EachCharIndex.cpp).

Mas em C++ ficaria melhor ainda assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    string a = "123456789";
    for (char& c : a) cout << c;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/W8BHDR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kjkzcdbc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/EachCharItem.cpp).

Comment: Entendi, mas como eu armazeno isso pra comparar os números, por exemplo tem "123456789" e eu pego apenas o 2 pra ver se é par e primo?

Comment: A sua pergunta não era sobre isso, mas para armazenar em uma variável é só fazer como estava fazendo, eu preferi mandar para o console para você ver funcionando.